# How to create a both consumer and producer (RabbitMQ) app with Micronaut

Tags: java, rabbitmq, micronaut

Hi: I'm trying to create a RabbitMQ consumer and producer in the same app for two different RabbitMQ instances.

I have this configuration:

```
rabbitmq:
  servers:
    analytics:
      host: 172.30.0.20
      port: 5672
      consumer-executor: "rabbit1"
    filtered:
      host: 172.30.0.21
      port: 5672
      consumer-executor: "rabbit2"
```

My ChannelPoolListener have this configuration

```
        channel.exchangeDeclare("rabbit1", BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT, true);
        channel.queueDeclare("rabbit1", true, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind("rabbit1", "rabbit1", "rabbit1");


        channel.exchangeDeclare("rabbit2", BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT, true);
        channel.queueDeclare("rabbit2", true, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind("rabbit2", "rabbit2", "rabbit2");
```

My Listener:

```
    @Queue("rabbit2")
    public void updateBook(Book book) {
        consumerService.consume(book);
    }
```

And my client:

```
    @Binding(value = "rabbit1")
    void publish(Book book);
```

My problem is that I am getting this exception when app starts:

```
Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.rabbitmq.connect.DefaultChannelPool]

Message: No bean of type [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('rabbit2'). 
* [ExecutorService] requires the presence of a bean of type [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.EventLoopGroupConfiguration] with qualifier [@Named('rabbit2')].
```

I tried to add this configuration to my application.yml

```
  executors:
    rabbit1:
      type: FIXED
    rabbit2:
      type: FIXED
```